# Fixing deep dents in floorboards

Tags: repair, hardwood-floor

We have deep dents (5mm at deepest) in our hardwood floor caused by strong blows with a baseball bat (crackhead subtenant, psychotic episode). Those dents are bigger than the dents that I've seen fixed by the [water + iron method](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/15690), and there is some breakage in the wood fibres. It seems the floor has a lacquer or shellack finish, not oiled.

What options are there for us to fix the floor, save completely replacing it? Not sure if sanding down everything is a viable option in this case.
Cost-efficient repair methods would be preferred, since we're not the home owners and have already pumped thousands into fixing the other damages, with no chance of reclaiming the damages.

[image: closeup photo of two dents in a hardwood floor]
[image: closeup photo of two dents in a hardwood floor]
[image: closeup photo of two dents in a hardwood floor]

Comment: You should replace the entire plank if you want to achieve seamlessness. See https://youtu.be/zOHt5erZlhQ and/or https://youtu.be/Ejz3B7ik07Q

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you for the video, this seems doable! Problem in this case is that the planks itself are 5 meters in length, and there are multiple ones damaged, it'd probably still result in having to replace the whole floor.

Comment: I see, you can just replace a small section of the plank. Not to be judgemental but if your previous tenant was a crackhead then I doubt your next tenant will expect perfect flooring.

Comment: This video could be more appropriate. https://youtu.be/DPGxCageub8

Comment: Does the entire floor look like the surface of a golf ball? If so then replacing the entire floor or covering it with a new floor (such as thin laminate) could be a better choice. Just patch the dents with wood putty before hand so that the new flooring doesn't crack due to inadequate support underneath. Please provide a zoomed out picture of the floor.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus kinda offtopic, but we didn't know what kind of person we'd be subletting the room to - seemingly completely normal guy up until shit hit the fan. Main problem is that we're not owners but renting. Thank you for your suggestions, the Youtube videos make it seem easy. It's focused on the center of the room but across multiple full length planks - still patching them up might be a solution. Probably should check in with the owner before those more invasive measures.